# Add methods in another method of a same class

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

I created 2 method (first, last) and a third one (sum); I want the sum of returned value of first and last and then stored in sum; then I want to display the returned value of the sum.

P.S. I am practicing class and object. This problem can be solved using very basic syntax but I want to learn the class and objects. I am telling this cause, you may think that why am I doing this when there are easier way to do that. ;)

Thanks

```
class Total:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def first(self):
        if self.x < 15:
            return self.x * self.y
        else:
            return self.x - self.y

    def last(self):
        if self.x < 100:
            return self.x + 5
        else:
            return self.x - 6

    def sum(self):
        pass
        # I need help here
        # add returned value of first() and last()


p = Total(25, 5)
p.sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `first()` and `last()` methods accumulated sum from the `sum()` method like:

```
class Total:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def first(self):
        if self.x < 15:
            return self.x * self.y
        else:
            return self.x - self.y

    def last(self):
        if self.x < 100:
            return self.x + 5
        else:
            return self.x - 6

    def sum(self):
        return self.first() + self.last()


p = Total(25, 5)
print(p.sum())
```

Output:

```
50
```

Comment: Thanks @arsho that helped a lot. I previously used the sum.methoed but I see that I didn't use the parenthesis. :)

Comment: @SandraRay, it would be helpful if you accept the answer.